# Does an electric field exert a force on the charge that produces it?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-fields, charge

I know that electric field will exert a force on any charge put in it, but are there any electric fields exert force on charge that produces it ? If not, why is it like that?

Comment: Just to be clear, are you asking if it is possible for an isolated charge to experience a force from the field that it produces?

Comment: I ask for the non-isolated charge and isolated case

Comment: So your answer to my question is yes, for the latter case?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, this is called the [Abraham-Lorentz force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abraham%E2%80%93Lorentz_force). It is not a force that exists on a charge which is moving at a constant velocity. It only affects an accelerating charge and it is related to the energy that is radiated away from the charge as it changes its acceleration.

Be aware that this is a classical formula. There are quantum mechanical versions of this formula, but this is a good approximation for many situations.

Comment: Interesting. Never heard of it. The Wikipedia article on it says it applies to an accelerating charge. For the charge to be accelerating doesn't it need to be subjected to a force by something else (another charge)?

Comment: Doesn't this assume that the charge is made up of smaller entities, a distribution, and that the force isn't a self force on any specific $\rho dv$ due to itself, but the force is due to OTHER $\rho dv$ elements of that charge.  This self force goes beyond the Abraham lorentz force and is a component of the net self force, hence the introduction of the concept of electromagnetic mass, where the inertia of a charged body is greater than the inertia of an uncharged body, as conducted by JJ Thompson.

Comment: @BobD yes. It will need a force to accelerate, as normal. The force could be an external EM field or a mechanical force or whatever

Comment: @jensenpaull no, if you look at the derivation you can see that it assumes a classical point charge

Comment: The derivation on Wikipedia relies on the larmor formula  which relies on the poynting vector  which relies on poyntings theorem. Poyntings theorem cannot be devised without assuming a distribution.  Since it assumes each $\rho dv $ element is negligible ( a non infinite charge density , which is only present with a distribution), which is inherent in the first statement of poyntings theorem derivation, that the force on a charge element is the due to the net E field, rather the E field minus the field produced by that element of charge. No one really talks about this very Important assumption

Comment: If you can show me a derivation of poyntings theorem for point charges I'd be eager to read. For a point charge containing a single charge density element, the contribution is not negligible, and the very first line in poyntings theorem derivation is ridiculous. This is touched on in griffiths in the context of EM energy for electrostatics,  from which the generalisation to a distribution from the point charge case is made  and he specifically states that his generalisation is only valid if the contribution of a single element is negligible.

Comment: The full effect of the self force assuming a distribution can be easily seen from analysing momentum conservation of the EM field whilst  adding an external non em force. The stress tensor integrated about the surface the charge is contained opposes this external force, (with  the assumption that the external force is the applied force to any object) causing a net "EM mass"

Comment: @jensenpaull said “Poyntings theorem cannot be devised without assuming a distribution”. I disagree. Poynting’s theorem can be derived from Maxwell’s equations without restricting the form of the sources. You are posting way too much in comments.

Comment: Please can you show me the derivation? The first line in the derivation assumes a non infinite charge density. Incompatible with point charges. $$F = [\rho \vec{E}_{net} + \vec{J} × \vec{B}_{net}] dv$$ What about this statement seems correct to you when dealing with point charges?

Comment: @Dale Yes, but I believe the OP originally talked about an "isolated charge", though it may have been edited out.

Comment: @jensenpaull see https://web.mit.edu/6.013_book/www/book.html section 11.2. If that is insufficient for you then please open an actual question on the topic. This is far too much for comments

Comment: I'd rather not post another question, since I can derive poyntings theorem, my comments are in relation to your answer. The derivation linked starts with the same line I did. Please do the following: Starting with the lorentz force, find the force on the single point charge. What is the value of E that you use? The field produced by itself + the other charge,  or the field produced by  JUST the other charge.

Comment: @jensenpaull no. Since you are unwilling to post a question and I am unwilling to continue in comments there is nothing left to do. The MIT derivation is sufficient to disprove your claim that “Poyntings theorem cannot be devised without assuming a distribution”. At least to my satisfaction if not yours

Answer (score 3):

For the question of whether or not the electric field of an isolated charge can exert a force upon the charge producing the field, I believe the answer is no.

Per Newton's 3rd law, all forces occur in pairs. In order for the charge in your example to be subjected to a force then it must exert an equal and opposite force on something else (e.g., another charge), and vice versa. It seems Newton's 3rd law would preclude an isolated charge from exerting a force upon itself.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The electromagnetic field itself can carry momentum. The charge isn't really isolated.